# Java: Convert date 2011-Jan-01 to format of dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: java, date, datetime, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I need to convert date (2011-Jan-01) to any of the simpledateformats.

The eclipse designer uses Java 7.

```
    String pDate = obj.getJSONArray("product").getJSONObject(i).getString("createdDate");
    //"2011-Jan-01" - date format.
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date fDate = format.parse(pDate);
        System.out.println("jsonDate: " + fDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("pDate: " + pDate);//"2011-Jan-01"


            errors:
            error:java.text.ParseException:Unparseable date:"2011-Jan-01"
            error: at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:348)
```

I'm getting errors above.

Comment: Does the string date have `HH:mm:ss` part?

Comment: Date formate is "2011-Jan-01". Thanks.

Comment: but why does you format have that part? (and why Java 7? there are better classes for time/date in Java 8 {actual version is 13})

Comment: just remove `HH:mm:ss` from your SimpleDateFormat, will work fine.

Comment: On Java 7 consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Your parsing format should not include the time (because your input is only the date), and you need another format call to produce your desired output. Something like,

```
String pDate = "2011-Jan-01";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
try {
    Date fDate = format.parse(pDate);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(fDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which outputs

```
01-01-2011
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTen Backport

This works on Java 7 (details below):

```
    DateTimeFormatter jsonDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MMM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter outputDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");

    String pDate = "2011-Jan-01";
    LocalDate fDate = LocalDate.parse(pDate, jsonDateFormatter);
    pDate = fDate.format(outputDateFormatter);

    System.out.println("Formatted date: " + pDate);
```

Output from the snippet is:

> Formatted date: 01-01-2011

Unless you have strong reasons not to, I recommend that you use one of Java’s built-in formats for your user’s locale rather than hardcoding an output format. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.UK);
```

Now the output is:

> Formatted date: 01-Jan-2011

### Question: Why java.time?

The old datetime classes that you tried to use in the question, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are poorly designed, the latter notoriously troublesome. Fortunately they are also long outdated. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Java 7? How?

Yes, java.time works nicely on Java 7. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");` to `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");`